# How to fix 'Concatenation problem' in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I write a function and try to add two number on it, But when I use ' + ' operator between two operators it's concate them. On the other hand if I use '-' operator then no problem. How can I fix it ?

```js
var a = prompt("Enter value of a : ");
var b = prompt("Enter value of b : ");

sum(a, b);

function sum(a, b){
    document.write("A + B = "+ (a+b) );   
}
```

Comment: You just need to parse them to numbers before addition

Comment: Edited and solve. Parse the variable to number data types.

Comment: @MahbuburRahman do _not_ make edits that modify the intent of the original code. With that edit in place, the question no longer even makes sense.